# 7 port powered USB hub backfeeding to my PC

Tags: power-supply, usb, motherboard

I just bought two 7 port usb hubs: [LogiLink UA0124](http://www.logilink.com/showproduct/UA0124.htm?seticlanguage=en). Just to run into a strange situation.

I did some servicing to my PC today and disconnected the main power cord from the PSU. Only to find out that all my usb devices(connected to other usb ports on the PC) are still powered up! 
At first I thought that I somehow accidentally  managed to make a perpetuum mobile!!!

When my euphoria run out I figured out that the hubs are giving a constant 5 volts to the PC port (backfeeding), even when I turn off the switch on the usb hub!
I also noticed that the processor fan has a small movement like twitching every 5 seconds...

So there must be some weird current running through my motherboard.
What should I do? This does not seem like some no name cheap product. So I wonder why is it designed in this way. Is it OK when the PC is powered up? I mean does the default voltage of the PC usb port counteract with this one and everything is fine? In that case I should only watch out when turning off the PC? Or is this something serious that could damage my other components?

**UPDATE**

As per request in the comments, I'm adding few pictures here. And many more on this [LINK (LogiLink 7 port USB HUB dismantled)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENtcG.jpg)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you open the enclosure of your hub and take a picture of the PCB? Properly designed hubs usually have (at least) a hub controller IC and power switch IC(s). It's also possible to cut corners in the design and leave out the power switches. Then it's more likely to back-power the PC.

Comment: Is this a _powered_ USB hub? It shouldn't do this and it can cause weird problems on the PC side.

Comment: I will dismantle one now and take a picture. I also updated my question. Because I was not quite clear, when the PC is OFF(power cord disconnected) and hub is OFF(switch). The devices on the hub do not have power anymore(Although there is a measurable voltage on the usb hub ports still, around 2 volts, that discharges in the next 1 minute. I don't know if that is normal either). However the devices on the PCs other USB ports do have power, because of the backfeeding!

Comment: yup it's a powered usb hub. The power adapter is declared as 5V/3.5A ...

Comment: Yeah, looks like the +5V line from your PC is directly connected to the +5V line of the hub's own PSU as long as the hub is switched on...

Comment: I now tried cutting off the +5V line(red) so no power is connected to PC ... I thought that maybe the motherboard will then not recognize the hub. But it did! It's working fine as long as I keep its own power adapter connected. But is it OK to keep it running like that?!

Comment: I am not sure on this qtn. i don't know when the local power is removed whether the hub is connected to PC (upstream port) or not? Whether the Upstream port is connected to PC when power is removed..?                                                Because, these hubs generally will take power from upstream port or local power and distribute to downstream ports(peripherals) using power switches. When local power is off also, lesser current can be available for downstream ports at 5V.

Comment: the german Computer Magazin c't had not long ago (issue nr. 18/2014) an very interesting article about this theme - if you understand german language it's worth reading it: "Strom von hinten/USB-Hubs können PCs und Notebooks beschädigen" ("Current from behind/USB-Hubs can damage PCs and Notebooks"). For example they say that the old version of a Belkin F5U404cw USB-Hub was working correctly, but the new one (!) wasn't - little strange?! :-)

Comment: Perhaps you could include a bit of a translation from that article to make it a clear answer to the question for anyone that can't read the article?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I eventually ended up cutting the +5V(red) line going from the hub to the PC. The only drawback is that the hub obviously needs to be connected to its own power supply to work.