# How do I test a USB drive to be sure it is not a “USB killer”

Tags: high-voltage, usb-device, tester

I have recently read of a dangerous USB drive containing a circuit instead of storage, that destroys the hardware of a computer by injecting a high voltage, high current pulse into the port it is plugged into. See [this article](http://hackaday.com/2015/03/11/killer-usb-drive-is-designed-to-fry-laptops/)

It should be easy to test an unknown USB drive for this sort of danger by plugging it into a separate test module before taking the risk of inserting it into a computer's USB port. Does such a test module exist? Is there a commercial version, a circuit or kit that can be obtained?

Having read that article I would routinely test every USB device before using it.

Comment: Remove the casing and check what is inside. In the article there are a couple of pretty big capacitors, in a USB drive should be nothing like that.

Comment: I see this as paranoia. 1. Why would you plug in an unknown device? 2. The odds of actually coming across a "USB killer" are astronomical. 3. USB is probably one of the most hardened buses in existence. I find it very hard to believe that a bus designed for typical consumer use and abuse could actually be damaged by 110V pulses.

Comment: @MattYoung -- considering that it's possible to fry Ethernet ports by crossing them to 120V mains despite that pesky isolation transformer, I wouldn't give a USB port much of a chance against a power cross event.

Comment: "hardened busses" bit of an over-exaggeration... it might be designed to mitigate ESD (if some effort was put in) but 110V... what about amps...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That's an apples to potatoes comparison.

Comment: @MattYoung -- I was using Ethernet as an example of a bus that is considered *much* more hardened than USB is in practical service.

Comment: @JonRB See IEC6100-4-2. ESD pulses are in the tens of amps.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I strongly disagree that Ethernet is more hardened than USB. Either way, plugging in a random USB device is unfathomably stupid.

Comment: @MattYoung I am aware of that and just like the DO160/ABD100 ( 1500V:80A ) for lightning is for a SHORT PERIOD OF TIME (IEC6100: 100ns,  DO160: 1us). The steering diodes/TVS can handle that for a short time. such USB killers are there for seconds if not longer.

Comment: @JonRB -- exactly.  TVS diodes can't take the abuse of a power cross condition.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it's possible to destroy ethernet ports by crossing them to RS232 (+/- 12V 1200 ohms) USB is tougher than that, (BTDT).  to destroy USB ports all that's needed to do is short D+ and/or or D- to a strong voltage  source (like +5V)

Comment: You are wasting your time. But according to the article, it applies a large DC voltage to the data lines. So you could easily design a test module which supplies 5V, just like a real USB port, and hook a volt meter to the data lines. If the death disk applies 100V to the data lines, don't plug it in to your computer. The other test method is to plug it into a disposable computer, then watch for smoke.

Comment: A $5 USB hub is probably a good enough testing device.

Comment: @MattYoung Why are you so upset and what are you actually getting at? Are you claiming that it's stupid to plug in a USB device you just bought in the store? Because that's essentially a random device until you have opened it up and analyzed it.

Comment: @pipe I'm not upset. What I'm getting at is this is a really dumb thing to worry about.

Comment: @MattYoung That I can agree to.

Comment: @pipe if you don't trust a retail sealed product, I wonder how you test your food prior to eating it.

Comment: @Passerby I trust retail products, and I also trust "unknown" USB devices. You should perhaps redirect your comments to the person who asked the question, who is the one who "would routinely test every USB device before using it".

Comment: remotely related question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/94382

Comment: There are probably 10-100 USB killers in the world (I can't find one for sale, only schematics). And there are probably 10 billion USB sticks in the world. I'd say the odds of being struck by lighting are much, much greater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is also the option of just not picking up any USB device you see and joyfully plugging it into whatever computer is nearest, as a general rule.

Back when Floppies (any size, really) were the thing and people owning a computer possessed some sensibility about it, this was actually general common sense. Go to an exhibition, get disks, think *very, very hard* about whether you want to put those in your main Atari/MSX/Whatever/PC.

Not because disks could generate high voltage and destroy all your hardware, but because they can also contain any kind of software that could do any kind of whatever.

Sure, modern operating systems are a bit more protective about "hey, this thing wants to install and it offers a driver itself, cool, here we go!" or "hey, this says auto run the software, and GO!". But funny thing, there are still plenty of holes and especially so in USB devices that combine multiple purposes.

Ever tried a Sandisk Cruzer on a fresh Windows install? Cool huh, that it offers to install software for you! If you have some security options disabled in up to Windows 7, it may even do that without telling you. Now think about someone like that monkey brain, but with more of a sense for software than hardware.

That said, here's your schematic for the destroyer detector:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqpZ5l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If D3 flashes there are spikes higher than 6.5V on the USB VCC, if D4 flashes there are spikes higher than 4.5V on the USB data lines.

The 1N4148 diodes are only to protect against high energy spikes forcing an insane base current through the relatively modest 20k resistor, now that flows through those diodes first. Still a lot can break, of course, but this could be mass produced at the one or two dollar range, excluding the power source. If you see it as a discardable tool, you can leave out the 1N4148 diodes and the 3.3k resistors.

The 1N4007 protects the power source against spikes on the power up to several hundreds of volts (though if you expect those, remove the capacitor or get one rated for hundreds of volts, or that one might pop).

When the diodes flash faintly the "violation" is small (10V spikes or such), when it flashes brightly the spikes are high voltage and probably high energy.

But, of course, mass producing this is an absolute and utter waste of your money and I see this as a simple course of "You don't always need complicated electronics to detect things" tutorialing, rather than "here's a real problem that needs a real solution".

Comment: Thank you Asmyldof for a comprehensive and useful answer. Thanks to all who commented for an interesting discussion, especially to those who read my question carefully, and also followed the link. My statement "I would routinely test every USB device before using it" was a bit tongue-in-cheek -- for most USB sticks there would be good evidence that it is genuine: being new from a branded range; seeing it removed from a computer; or asking the donor to plug it in his own computer. A tester like the one described would be a last resort.

Comment: This circuit does not help, if the USB Killer is a little bit more intelligent and activates the high voltage with a delay, or on an event (reading special block, or file).

Answer (score 0):

Get a cheap USB wall charger. Open and modify it so that the data lines are shorted together and add a current limiter to the Vbus pin. Now when ever you plug a drive in. It will be powered. If it's a USB killer, when it sends the pulse on the data line it should blow up quite nicely. Thus if the USB stick explodes, it was a USB killer.

But seriously, just use a cheap wall charger. If the charger stops working then you might want to question the USB drive. No computer anywhere to take damage.

Comment: Oh goody, a down vote with no comment.

Comment: Presumably someone downvoted it because the linked article says it puts the pulse on the data lines, so it's not likely to damage a charger.

Comment: Presumably the killer USB device only has one pulse-charge in its super capacitor. Thus, it'd be spent on the first device it sees.

Comment: @RoboKaren If you read the linked article about the device in question you can learn that it does not use supercapacitors, and will keep cycling high voltage + high current pulses until the target is fried.

Comment: Interesting design, thanks! It uses a DC-DC boost from the USB V+ to create a 110v charge that then gets dumped onto the data lines. Ingenious and evil.

Comment: @PeterJ, well then they should look up USB charging standards. The USB data lines are used to measure voltages from the device that correspond to different charging currents. Thus the IC would blow on the pulse. Pretty easy to see and only loses you a charger. If it's just a dummy 5V source, then trying the lines wouldn't damage a flash drive but a USBKiller would likely destroy itself, depending on it's tolerances.

Comment: @Dave, don't see that happening myself - the charger will just have a couple of resistors to set that voltage (it's up to the device to respect it) and if the USBKiller couldn't handle that voltage on the data lines it would self-destruct itself no matter what was connected.

Comment: @PeterJ, you're right, it's just burn the data wires off if they were shorted. Herm, I guess putting step down transformer with two anti-parallel LEDs as a load could act as an indicator. It'd be a custom transformer.

Comment: Typical USB charger shorts D+ and D- together. If you actually want to design something, put a high impedance voltage divider from D+ (and or D-) to GND, and measure the divider voltage with an ADC. If the voltage applied to D+ and/or  D- is greater than VBUS, then the device is suspect. But, again, this is a waste of time.